# Auditing of Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql, logging, event-log, syslog, audit

I would like to enable auditing of Mysql Server both on Windows and Linux. I am working on collecting logs from MySQL server for a log analyzer tool. So, I first need to know how to enable auditing of all possible queries like error, warning, success and information.

1) How to enable auditing in MySQL(any version) in Windows and Linux.

2) How to send the logs to syslog(Unix) and EventLog(Windows)?

Can anyone share a step wise solution for the above questions?

I added the below lines in my.ini but I could restart the mysql server due to the below lines. If I remove these lines and restart, the server will restart successfully.

```
log_output="FILE"
general_log=1
general_log_file="E:\Logs\my-sql-general-log.log"

slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="my-sql-slow-log.log"
long_query_time=10
```

I tried with only general log and faced the same issue. I also tried general_log=on and general_log=1. Found no change.

I tried the above change on Windows 10 with MySQL Server 5.0

**EDIT 1 :**

I added the below line in my.ini

```
log="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/logs/general-log.log"
```

After adding the above line, the query logs were written in the file. The errors are still not written and they are not forwarded to Event Viewer.

**EDIT 2 :**

1) I added the below lines to **my.ini** in my Windows machine

```
log="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/logs/my-sql-general-log.log"
log_bin="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/logs/my-sql-bin-log.log"
log_error="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/logs/my-sql-error-log.log"

log_slow_queries
long_query_time = 1
```

In this case, all the queries are written to the general log but errors are not written to the error log. In error log, only the start/stop of mysql service logs are written.

**(i)** How to write errors like 'No database selected' or 'Table does not exist' to the error log file?

**(ii)** If I add log-output=TABLE in my.ini, the mysql service won't restart. What causes this issue? It works fine in Linux.

**(iii)** How to send these logs to EventViewer?

2) I added the below lines to **my.cnf** in my Linux machine

```
[mysqld_safe]
syslog

[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log = 1

log_error = /var/logs/mysql/error.log
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes

log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

After adding these lines, the general logs are sent to the syslog server but not the error logs.

**(i)** How to write errors like 'No database selected' or 'Table does not exist' to the error log file and send them to syslog server?

**(ii)** I also tried `log-output=TABLE` but when logs are written to table, it is not sent to syslog server. How do I send the logs to syslog server if the logs are written to table?

The General Log is written like below -

```
181017 11:46:41       1 Connect     root@localhost on 
                      1 Query       set autocommit=1
                      1 Query       SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
                      1 Query       SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
                      1 Query       SELECT current_user()
                      1 Quit
```

Is there a way to make the logs to be written like below ?

```
Time               User             ThreadID   Command     Argument
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Connect     root@localhost on 
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Query       set autocommit=1
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Query       SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Query       SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Query       SELECT current_user()
181017 11:46:41    root@localhost   1          Quit
```

**EDIT 3 :** 
I was able to send all the logs to syslog by modifying the rsyslog.conf file but I'm still unable to forward the general and slow query logs to Windows EventLog.